# pass NSString variable to other class with NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I want to pass a NSString from one class to another class and add that NSString to an NSMutableArray in my second class. I'm believe i can use NSNotification for this, but i don't know how to pass an variable over notification. My code would something like this:

//class1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *variableString;

@end
```

//class1.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize variableString = _variableString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setVariableString:@"test"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"pasteString" object: _variableString];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

//class2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *arr;

@end
```

//class2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize arr = _arr;


- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated   
{
[super viewDidLoad];
if(_arr == nil)
{
    _arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"pasteString" object:nil]; 
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
NSString *theString = [notification object];
[_arr addObject:theString];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In sender class you can post a notification with an object with something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: NOTIFICATION_NAME object: myString];
```

The listener or receiver class has to register for the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:NOTIFICATION_NAME object:nil];
```

The method incomingNotification is:

```
- (void) incomingNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
   NSString *theString = [notification object];
   ...
}
```

### EDIT

When you post the notification from "ViewController", is "ViewController2" loaded?

Comment: I updated my code above, but it's not working for me. Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Is ViewController2 being invoked?

Comment: No, i forgot to segue over to viewcontroller2. This code work now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Its working fine.But I want send value from View Controller1 to View Controller2 .. In  which place i call post notification.

Comment: for new folks (me), i believe also need to '[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];' in viewWillDisappear or dealloc method in the receiver/lisener class. (thank you Jonatthan)

Answer (score 0):

```
Send your Notification like this:

        if(isComingFromHowToUseThisApp) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noteFromVideoPlayer"
                                                            object:@"fromHowToUseThisApp"];
    }else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"noteFromVideoPlayer"
                                                            object:@"fromVideoPlayerViewiPad"];
    }

Receive your notification like this:

// Reset the default value of table view in master split view
- (void)defaultCellSelectionOfTableView:(NSNotification *) objNotification {


     // We need to change the default selection of row
    NSString *noticeFromVideoPlayer = [objNotification object];

}// end defaultCellSelectionOfTableView
```