# passing data using Notification,iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass NSString variable to other class with NSNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272068/pass-nsstring-variable-to-other-class-with-nsnotification)

My question is : is it possible we can pass data from one to another view controller using postNotificationName and addObserver from notification class in Iphone

Answer (score 18):

You can pass data in the userDictionary element of the API call

```
NSDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          anObject, @"objectName", 
                          anotherObject, @"objectId",
                          nil] autorelease];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AnythingAtAll" object:nil userInfo:aDictionary];
```

You can retrieve the dictionary from the inbound notification that you observe. Add the observer in advance of posting the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(anyAction:) name:@"AnythingAtAll" object:nil];
```

this might be in your init method or a viewDidLoad method

```
-(void)anyAction:(NSNotification *)anote
{
NSDictionary *dict = [anote userInfo];
AnyClass *objectIWantToTransfer = [dict objectForKey:@"objectName"];
}
```

note that you should remove your object as an observer in the dealloc method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. However, how you are so that you **addObserver** first then do **postNotificationName** later on. At [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283014/can-not-catch-a-notification-in-iphone), I do the same thing as you do but the **selector** is not being called after all.

Comment: Yes to clarify you need to add the observer before you post the notification. Usually that will be in the init or viewdidload methods.

Comment: I need some more examples.. please give some more examples link about postnotifications.