# Notifying multiple view controllers and passing a value back to the notifier

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotification

I need to send a message to multiple objects at a time, and then pass a value back from each. Delegates can be used only one at a time, and notifications cannot return values.

Is there any way that a tab bar controller containing two view controllers can notify both of them at the same time, with return values?

Comment: you can pass value in using Notifications...

Comment: @SunnyShah and how you will return values using notification?

Comment: @S.J why you can't simply wrap it in some method which will return a value you need but also sends a notification ? If I understand the problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass NSString variable to other class with NSNotification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272068/pass-nsstring-variable-to-other-class-with-nsnotification)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the question is how to have the recipient of the notification to send a response back to the sender of the notification.

You can't just return a value from a notification. But the notification handler can call a method back in the original object in order to supply whatever data you wanted to pass back to it.

One way to do that is to supply an `object` parameter of `postNotificationName` that specifies who sent the notification. And then have that `object` (the `notificationSender`) conform to some protocol with some established API. For example, define a protocol for the method that the view controllers will call:

```
@protocol MyNotificationProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)didReceiveNotificationResponse:(NSString *)response;

@end
```

Then, the object issuing the notification would conform to this protocol:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <MyNotificationProtocol>
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (void)notify
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = ...;

    // note, supply a `object` that is the `notificationSender`

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationName object:self userInfo:userInfo];
}

- (void)didReceiveNotificationResponse:(NSString *)response
{
    NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
}

@end
```

Then, the view controllers that receive the notification could use the `object` parameter of the `NSNotification` object to send the response:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveNotification:) name:kNotificationName object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    id<MyNotificationProtocol> sender = notification.object;

    // create your response to the notification however you want

    NSString *response = ...

    // now send the response

    if ([sender conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyNotificationProtocol)]) {
        [sender didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
    }
}
```

In the above example, the response is a `NSString`, but you could use whatever type of parameter to `didReceiveNotificationResponse` that you want, or add additional parameters (e.g. the `sender` of the response).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a key-value pair and pass that in a notification's userInfo dictionary:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:myNotification object:nil userInfo:myDictionary];
```

In the method where you handle the notification:

```
- (void)handleMyNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     NSDictionary *myDictionary = notification.userInfo;
}
```

Comment: and how you will return values using notification?

Comment: The values are in your dictionary.  Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass user info dictionary to the notification:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isReachable] 
                                                 forKey:@"isReachable"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reachabilityChanged" object:self userInfo:dataDict];
```

It seems that the problem is different then I thought before. If you just want to send notification and return some value right after inside the object which sends the notification I would probably wrap it with some method

```
- (NSString *)notifyAboutSomethingFancy
{
  //the code from above  
  return @"whatever you want to return";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification to pass value to different controllers

Check the relevant link.

[pass data in the userDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287741/passing-data-using-notification-iphone)

Comment: Before vote down you should be sure that answer is wrong. don't vote down according to your understating.

Comment: I definitely agree with @Sunny , whether it solves the problem or not but down vote is unjustified